# Can you vent a bathroom out of a furnace vent?

Tags: bathroom, vent, exhaust-fan

I have furnace vent which is a simple stack from the furnace out the attic roof. Can I with a sawzall and some silicon affix a bathroom vent to that so it also goes out the ceiling?

Would that be dangerous or a violation of code? It's just steam, farts, and humidity.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is dangerous.

Yes it is a code violation.

Please don't modify your furnace flue.

Comment: @Rohit I don't know which question you're looking at.  This one literally asks "Would that be dangerous" and I gave a direct answer.

Comment: You are correct, so I have deleted it.

Answer (score 1):

Might be against the rules here, but I just wanna [quote](https://www.diychatroom.com/threads/vent-bathroom-fan-to-furnace-vent.8135/):

> All it takes is a snow storm. Snow gets high enough and blocks the flue discharge. Instead of the furnace's pressure switch shutting down the unit it will just pump into the bathroom fan and kill you and the rest of the family. That will leave you some legacy! Dumb idea. Just plain dumb.

This question is also a re-post [Can an existing furnace flue be used to vent bathroom exhaust fan](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/31295/can-an-existing-furnace-flue-be-used-to-vent-bathroom-exhaust-fan)

Comment: I would have found that if the tagging situation on this site wasn't so bad.. thanks

Comment: @EvanCarroll i have found these by googling "bathroom vent connected to furnace"